# weak variable with a strong reference in a block: does not create a retain cycle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, retain-cycle

why does it work when we pass the weak reference to a strong reference inside the block? If a local variable in a block is retained, this should add a retain to `self` and thus create this bad retain cycle?

Here is the example :

```
__weak id weakSelf = self; 
[self.operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSNumber* result = findLargestMersennePrime();
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{ 
        MyClass* strongSelf = weakSelf; 
        strongSelf.textLabel.text = [result stringValue];
    }]; 
}];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create or copy a block (it could be copied when you, for example, schedule it to gcd), referenced variables are captured (unless declared with __block specifier). Strong references are retained, weak references are not.

When you create local `strongSelf` variable it keeps `self` alive while block **executes** (i.e. while it's not executed and sits in a property there's no strong reference). When you reference `self` directly - `self` is captured and retained, now it keeps `self` while **block is alive**.

```
__weak id weakSelf = self; 
[self.operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSNumber* result = findLargestMersennePrime();
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{ 

        MyClass* strongSelf = weakSelf; // strong reference when block executes
        [self foo]; // strong reference when block created/copied

        strongSelf.textLabel.text = [result stringValue];
    }]; 
}];
```

See the difference? If you kill all strong pointers to object with direct `self` reference there is still one strong reference inside the block, the one which was captured and retained. At the same time local `strongSelf` pointer only holds strong reference to `self` while block is executed, so, if `self` was already dead, `weakSelf` would be nil and `strongSelf` will get nil value.

Answer (score 1):

no it doesn't create a cycle since self isn't captured as strong! :)

strongSelf is a strong reference that retains self BUT since strongSelf is a local var, it is released when the block is done and the retain count drops fine